# Get time data last changed in redis using rredis

Tags: r, redis

I have some data stored in redis which I am accessing through R using the package rredis. Is it possible to find that time which a piece of data stored in redis (in my particular example a hash) last changed from within the R terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Redis does not maintain the timestamp of a key's last update. It is possible, however, to implement this type of behavior "manually" by adding this logic to your application's code.